# Is there any way to create apps for tizen os using flutter?

Tags: flutter, tizen-wearable-sdk

Greetings to the stackoverflow developers

I need to create apps and do some experiments in Tizen OS which is installed in Samsung gear S3

I know that the fossil watches are fully compatiable with wearable OS developed by google and it supports flutter but in my case i need LTE support on my watch so i choose Samsung gear S3 but

is there anyways to build apps for this Tizen OS in Samsung S3?

If anyone know the way or got any refernces please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you can use this: https://github.com/flutter-tizen/flutter-tizen
it supports galaxy watch with Tizen 4.0 (2018) or later

Answer (score 1):

Not possible for now, with Flutter you can create Android, iOS, Web and Desktop apps.

Comment: Thanks for the information but i found some procedure for developing apps for wear OS   https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-building-wearos-app-fedf0f06d1b4  thats why I am showing interest in Tizen

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Tizen Application using Flutter(at now, beta version). but, Galaxy Store is not yet ready for Flutter Application Type. Galaxy Store will be ready after 2 month..